# Extract data from output

Tags: php

I have the below output displayed on my screen which is assigned to a variable

```
<pre>
$content = First Name: ajkhfsadf
Last Name: asdfasf
password: jkasdfhasdf2234h234j23 (encrypted. variable length)
objectClass: asdfjkashdf
</pre>
```

the above rows in the output can change order. Is there a way I can extract only the password field and replace it with ******?

I have a static workaround which requires me to pre-select the words but it doesn't work with the code as the output rows can be dynamic in order.

```
$word1 = "password: ";
$word2 = "objectClass";
$word3 = "Password: ******** \n";
$between=substr($contents, strpos($contents, $word1), strpos($contents, $word2) - strpos($contents, $word1));
$output = str_replace($between,$word3,$contents);
```

Is there a way to be able to select password row only and replace the encrypted password with ***** regardless of its position in the output?

Comment: Are you doing this so that your textbox shows only *'s for the password field ? please clarify!

Comment: yes thats correct as i dont want to reveal the password even if its encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/Password: .*/', 'Password: ********', $string);
```

Comment: +1 because it's much simpler that my answer. Wish I knew regex :/

Comment: i dont think there is a function called replace_regexp in php. i am getting function error. Call to undefined function replace_regexp()

Comment: Brain fart, it's preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

You use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). I assume you read the *entire* output in one go and store it in a variable `$var`.

First you explode `$var` using the linebreak `\n` as a delimeter. You now have all rows separate.

Now you loop around the rows, further exploding each one on `:` and check the first component of your new array to see if it matches `password`. Reconstruct the array (with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) and you're done.

Bonus: By replacing all characters of `$password` with a star you give the attacker the advantage of knowing how many characters the password has (unless your encryption scheme outputs fixed-length strings).

Comment: i will be replacing it with only 8 stars regardless of the length of the encrypted password or remove that field all together.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment, then you don't need to mask this value when you retrieve it from the database, or which ever storage you're using;

what you need to do is make your textbox look like this in HTML:

```
<input type="password" value="...Stored Password...">
```

Be warned though, this is not very secure!

what are you trying to achieve ultimately ?

Comment: the response is coming from a shell script that runs on the machine. i am just trying to mask the password field with *****